# Vue.js which is the right way to send props as flags to v-show?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, flags, vue-props

For example, I have two async services. Let's assume that both services are available in the moment of app loading and signal that by returning true. I have two properties ('servconn' and 'netconn') that receive those boolean flags. Then I'm passing these two properties to a separate component as props. On that separate component, I have two alert boxes that show depending on the availability of the services.

If you look at the example sandbox, the problem is that the alert boxes are staying still before the component receives flags.

Of course, if I change initial flags to true in the data() section then all works but it's logically not correct and also, flags can be different depending on services availability. Which is the right way to accomplish this? Is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Click the refresh sandbox icon button to see how it works.
[Here is the Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-prop-send-flag-uunql?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Initialize your data values to `null` instead of false, and display the alerts only when the value is exactly false: `=== false`. That way, null and true won't display the alert.

Comment: if your app is dependent on said *services*, then it should check before loading the app and show that its checking then if any fail only then show the errors, else none will show and all is good. Normally one would only show the alert error if the services is down after an api call or such. But I suppose if you added a checked status and checks that was true then its known to be checked https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-prop-send-flag-forked-zmncg?file=/src/App.vue btw use v-if else you have a bunch of hidden alerts on the dom, v-show is only good if you need attach event handlers to it

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Thank you for your comment. Yes, `===false` would work as an option. But in this case, I have to remove the default type for received props, in another way use of null throws an error of the wrong type.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for your suggestions. Yes, that's why I decided to monitor services while showing a splash screen. What if I need to watch those properties to make a decision; is your example still applicable to it or it needs another approach? Do you think it's better to combine properties to one object to watch object? Because I'm also watching those `netconn` and `servconn` properties as well. For example, if the service responded and ready then do a task.

Comment: np, *Do you think it's better to combine properties to one object to watch object?* for sure, or use vuex

Comment: in the watcher, you can do `'state.netconn':function()..` etc don't have to watch deep